# Centering a nested SVG responsively

Tags: html, svg, vector, graphics

I've been looking for a workaround for this problem but only found fixed solutions, while I'm looking for % transform solutions.

I have an svg inside another svg, something like this:

```
<svg
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
viewBox="0 0 331.45 409.46"
{...props}
> 
   <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 177.44 210.55"
      {...props}
   > </svg>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to center the nested svg inside of his parent? maybe using a g tag to wrap it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, move the upper left corner of the nested `<svg>` to the center, and then move it by half its width to the left and half the height to the top.

There are a lot of combinations of `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` and `transform` that can be set on the inner `<svg>` element. According to the SVG 2 spec, they all are [presentation attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html#PresentationAttributes), which mean you can write them either as attributes or as CSS style properties. The only restriction is that if you use `transform` as an attribute, you must not use units.

In practice, the implementations are still incomplete on most browsers, and a lot of variants fail. For example, the following should be possible, but does not work correctly in Chrome:

```
<svg>
  <svg width="120px" height="90px"
       style="transform: translate(calc(50% - 60px), calc(50% - 45px))"
       viewBox="0 0 200 150">
    <rect width="200" height="150" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

But it is possible to restrict yourself to what the SVG 1.1 spec allowed:

- write everything as attributes. `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` can have all sorts of units
- no `transform` on a `<svg>` element; instead use a `<g>` wrapper.

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<svg class="outer">
  <g transform="translate(-60 -45)">
    <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="120px" height="90px"
         viewBox="0 0 200 150">
      <rect width="200" height="150" />
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there any workarround to use % translate instead of pixels in the g wrapper of the inner svg? I really don't know the height and width of the inner svg since it's dinamic.

Comment: You can try which browsers support CSS transform on g elements. I suspect most do, but the information is not available as part of the usual databases about feature support.